# Can't access property of nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, data-structures, list-comprehension

I have a dictionary that has dictionaries inside it with the same items:

```py
my_dict = {
  "person_1" : {
     "name" : "Roberta",
     "income_ratio" : 0.89
  },
  "person_2" : {
     "name" : "Roberta",
     "income_ratio" : 0.89
  },
  "person_3" : {
     "name" : "Roberta",
     "income_ratio" : 0.89
  },
  "person_4" : {
     "name" : "Roberta",
     "income_ratio" : 0.89
  }
}
```

I want to store each `income_ratio` in a list and i'm using:

```py
incomes = []
for person in my_dict.items():
   incomes.append(person[1]["income_ratio"])
```

This works well, but for learning purposes i was looking for a more ~pythonic~ way of accomplish this result. Trying with list comprehension i get an error:

```py
incomes = [person[1]["income_ratio"] for person in my_dict.items()]


> TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable
```

Some guidance is very welcome.

Comment: where does `f1_score` come from? hope u looking for `[person[1]["income_ratio"] for person in my_dict.items()]`

Comment: sorry, it was a copy-paste error. Already fixed. The error is not related to this mistype. Your solution still throws this error.

Comment: `[person[1]["income_ratio"] for person in my_dict.items()]` works just fine

Comment: more cleaner way is `[person['income_ratio'] for person in my_dict.values()]`

Comment: `[stuff['income_ratio'] for (person,stuff) in d.items()]` - although the comprehension in your question works for me with no error. Please, always, post the complete Traceback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution:

```
[my_dict[k]['income_ratio'] for k in my_dict.keys()]
```